# Dragging Multiple Images

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to develop an analysing app that determines if you are "clever"
What this involves doing is taking a picture of yourself and dragging points onto your face, where the nose, mouth and eyes are. However, The code I have tried does not work:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    if ([touch view] == eye1) 
    {
        eye1.center = location;
    } 
    else if ([touch view] == eye2) 
    {
        eye2.center = location;
    } 
    else if ([touch view] == nose) 
    {
        nose.center = location;
    } 
    else if ([touch view] == chin)  
    {
       chin.center = location;
    }
    else if ([touch view] == lip1) 
    {
        lip1.center = location;
    }
    else if ([touch view] ==lip2) 
    {
        lip2.center = location;
    }
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    [self touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

What is happening, because when I just have a single image, it works, but is not helpful for me. What can I do to make it work? The spots start at the bottom of the screen in a "Toolbar" and then the user drags them onto the face. I kinda want the finished result to look like:

[image: http://gyazo.com/0ea444a0edea972a86a46ebb99580b2e]

Comment: Have you thought about using face detection? Also, what does the code do wrong? where are the images starting at?

Comment: You need to explain more:
"What is happening, because when I just have a single image, it works, but is not helpful for me. What can I do to make it work?"
What is not helpful? What is not working?

Comment: ...also, have you considered using gesture recognisers? They abstract away some of the complexity of `touchesMoved`/`touchesBegan`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two basic approaches:

1. You can use the various touches methods (e.g. `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved`, etc.) in your controller or the main view, or you can use a single gesture recognizer on the main view. In this situation, you'd use `touchesBegan` or, if using a gesture recognizer, a `state` of `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan`, determine `locationInView` of the superview, and then test whether the touch is over one of your views by testing `CGRectContainsPoint`, using the `frame` of the various views as the first parameter, and by using the `location` as the second parameter.

   Having identified the view that the gesture began, then in `touchesMoved` or, if in a gesture recognizer, a `state` of `UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged`, and move the view based upon the `translationInView`.
2. Alternatively (and easier IMHO), you can create individual gesture recognizers that you attach to each of the subviews. This latter approach might look like the following. For example, you first add your gesture recognizers:

   ```
   NSArray *views = @[eye1, eye2, lip1, lip2, chin, nose];

   for (UIView *view in views)
   {
       view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
       UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanGesture:)];
       [view addGestureRecognizer:pan];
   }
   ```

   Then you implement a `handlePanGesture` method:

   ```
   - (void)handlePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
   {
       CGPoint translation = [gesture translationInView:gesture.view];
       if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
       {
           gesture.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(translation.x, translation.y);
           [gesture.view.superview bringSubviewToFront:gesture.view];
       }
       else if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
       {
           gesture.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
           gesture.view.center = CGPointMake(gesture.view.center.x + translation.x, gesture.view.center.y + translation.y);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: This has helped! Thanks you so much!